# The easiest way to emulate line-spacing functionality instead of line-height

Tags: css

Let me explain my view of the difference between `line-spacing` (which I would like to emulate), and `line-height`, using this picture:

[image]

Here you can see text with `line-height > 1` inside a container with `padding`. An extra visual whitespace is added to the top and bottom of the text, and I want whitespace to be added between the lines only.

Why I (and you) may need this feature, emulated `line-spacing`? Because if you have buttons or images inside this container alongside with text with `line-height > 1`, text and images will look misaligned. Text has extra whitespace added to the top and the bottom, which causes edge of the text look more far from the container border.

To avoid this, I manually add negative margins to the text:

```
 h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 42px; /* or 1.4 */
    margin: -6px 0 -6px 0; 
 }
```

**So what's the problem?**

I am very dependent on `font-size` in pixels. I need to recalculate margins after every  change of font-size or line-height, and I have to calculate it for `h3`, `p` and so on.

I'm looking for some way to automate this (some magic I'm missing).

Comment: can you wrap each row into <span>?

Comment: do the margin in ems and then it will be relative to the font-size

Comment: @Pete still I can't give margins freely to my `h1`. I have to calculate the "fix" in my head every time.

Comment: Any SASS / LESS / Stylus solution?

Comment: - @Anon, I can not wrap each row, because these rows is just a continuous line of text